# all possible permutaions of bits

Tags: c++, permutation

Is there any build in function to find all perturbations of a given number of bits in a given length with tailing zeros?

To clarify: for `#bits = 2` and `#rows = 4`

gives

```
11000000
10100000
01100000
00110000
```

Is there any built in function in `c++` for this?

Edit: To clarify: I have a number (in this example 8Bit long) and I want to have all possible permutations of 4 bits when the number itself stays under a certain value (in this example: `1 << 4 + 1 << 3`)

Comment: no.. you have to implement by yourself..

Comment: Why not simply increment a counter (0-15, 4 bits here)? Shift it left as necessary (4 bits here). That will go through all permutations of bits.

Comment: @user2864740 Or just add the desired power of 2.

Comment: @user2864740 But I don't think that's what he's looking for (although it's not at all clear what he's looking for).

Comment: Hm okey, in this case this doesn't exist. I was just wondering if there already exist something since this is not such an umcommen problem. Thx for clarifications.

Comment: `std::next_permutation` on a `vector<bool>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> v(8);
    v[2] = v[3] = true;

    do {
        print(v);
    } while (std::next_permutation(begin(v), begin(v) + 4));
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/wACHMp)

Comment: Yes actually. This should work. I can afterwards convert it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const int bits = 2;
    const int rows = 4;
    const int numbits=8;

    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        std::cout << std::bitset<numbits>(i<<(numbits-bits)) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Notice that rows and numbits are quite superfluous and can be replaced if you only want all combinations:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const int bits = 2;
    for (int i=0;i<1<<bits;i++) {
        std::cout << std::bitset<bits>(i) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Both implementations do what @user2864740 also suggested: Count an integer up and print the binary representation. The first lets you choose how many to print and if you want trailing zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
std::vector<bool> bits;
/* fill it somehow */
do {
  /* something with bits */ 
} while(std::next_permutation(bits.begin(), bits.end()));
```

Comment: `std::bitset` doesn't have `begin`, `end`... have to stick to `vector<bool>`